# Comparison of `String Literal Types`

Tags: typescript, string, types, literals, type-traits

I tried to make static analysis of types (like `std::type_traits`) with TypeScript, and first I made `is_same<>`.
Classes and primitive types work fine, but String Literal Types have strange behavior.

```ts
type is_same<A, B> = A extends B ? B extends A ? true : false : false;
type _1 = is_same<"a" | "b", "a" | "b">;
type _2 = "a" | "b" extends "a" | "b" ? "a" | "b" extends "a" | "b" ? true : false : false;
```

The type obtained using `is_same<>` is `_1`. This type is `boolean`.
Next, The result of expanding `is_same<>` is `_2`. This type is `true`.
What is the difference between these results?

I confirmed with TypeScript 4.7.4.

Comment: other solution (what a genius) -> https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is caused by [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

By chaining the conditionals here the way you did, each member of the union is distributed individually to the next conditional.

To stop this, you can wrap `A` and `B` in a tuple.

```
type is_same<A, B> = [A] extends [B] ? B extends A ? true : false : false;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=75&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgzgfTgQwLYQDwEEA0UBCAfFALxQDaWAulBAB7AQB2AJnBfjQPwG0PNsoWKD2AAnAK7QAXFABmyADZwZ8pSoDcAKC2hIUBAEZSsRCnQYARMktQAPlEsAjS3mu2Hzy4W27w0BAAmE3d7Rxc%20RlZ2UM8Inljw23oowUSvEShxKShZBWVVfM0gA)

Comment: thank you! I read and understood the document you taught me.